# Prevent cache miss warnings with perform_caching on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I'm experimenting with caching in my Rails 3.2 app and enabled caching by adding this to my development.rb file:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Caching works as expected, except that when I load any page the console shows tons of these log entries:

```
Completed 200 OK in 1006ms (Views: 249.2ms)
cache: [GET /assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/chosen.jquery.min.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/bootstrap/tabs.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/jquery.notifications-1.1.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/jquery.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/jquery.tablesorter.min.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/spin.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/olark.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/simplemodal/basic.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/simplemodal/jquery.simplemodal.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/vendor_application.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/scrollto.jquery.min.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/bootstrap.css?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/scroller.jquery.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/application.js?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/application.css?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/simplemodal.css?body=1] miss
cache: [GET /assets/connections.js?body=1] miss
```

Should I be worried about those cache misses? Is there any way to fix that / silence them?

I'm using the asset pipeline and memcached with dalli.

Comment: I just noticed that when I have perform_caching set to true (even if I'm not actually using any caching) the load time for each fluctuates dramatically (900-1200ms in one case), but when I have perform_caching set to false the load time is constant at 1000ms. That doesn't seem right...

Comment: Also see this question I just opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340985/unexpected-memcache-gets-in-rails-3-2-app

Not the same issue as this question, but possibly related. As Chris comments above, my issue is about why rails is attempting to fetch things from cache when I have not configured it to cache any actions.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of Dalli (after 2.0.3) might resolve this issue. See: https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/207

[Mike's commit](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/commit/892020fbc73613ccc84412ce04b85b7fda645e63) today added silence! method. You will need to set `Rails.cache.silence!` on your initializer for this take effect.

You can update your gemfile to fetch the latest Dalli code from Github or wait for next version of Dalli gem to be released.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature from rack-rache, you can disable rack-cache like this:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = false
```

Rails issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7581