# Unexpected memcache GETs in rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My rails 3.2 app is trying to fetch values from the cache (memcached via dalli) that I'm not expecting it to be caching. It's not getting any cache hits, but I'm puzzled about what is going on. This happens with `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` on production as well as development, using WEBrick.

Here's a snippet of what I'm seeing in memcache verbose output:

```
<30 GET https://www.myrailsapp.com/?
>30 Writing an error: Not found
>30 Writing bin response:
>30   0x81 0x00 0x00 0x00
>30   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
>30   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x09
>30   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>30   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
>30   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<30 Read binary protocol data:
<30    0x80 0x00 0x00 0xd0
<30    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<30    0x00 0x00 0x00 0xd0
<30    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<30    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
<30    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Note that there is only a cache GET and I'm not seeing any cache writes.

I see similar cache GET attempts for all my actions, most of which are JSON API calls. All of them result in a cache miss. Like this,

```
<31 GET https://www.myrailsapp.com/api/somecall?param1=foo&param2=bar
>31 Writing an error: Not found
```

I have not specified any `caches_action` directives anywhere in my app.

Is this a rails bug?

If no, where should I look to stop these unnecessary cache GETs?

Thanks.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/issues/207) on dalli and the associated question about how to [prevent-cache-miss-warnings-with-perform-caching-on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353160/prevent-cache-miss-warnings-with-perform-caching-on?rq=1) seem related, but don't explain why rails is trying to GET these objects from the cache in the first place.

Comment: This issue is still unresolved. See github issue at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7581. If you have the time to investigate or have a solution already, please post there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per cswilliams on the Github thread you've posted:

It appears to be an issue with the `rack_cache` being enabled by default (since updated in the master branch).

Disabling it in your application or environments properties file (e.g., config/environments/development.rb) seems to resolve the issue:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = false
```

Comment: What is the implication of disabling rack_cache in this scenario?

Comment: You would not be able to use rack cache for its designed purpose of serving cached assets. If you don't have a lot of static assets then the impact is probably nil.